# Can't push to gemfury if gemspec uses __dir__

Tags: ruby

When I try to build a gem by pushing to the gemfury git remote (https://gemfury.com/help/git-push-package/), I get the following error:

```sh
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Initializing build: done.
remote: -----> Building package...
remote:        RubyGem build detected
remote:        Invalid gemspec in [/build/app/crm.gemspec]: undefined local variable or method `__dir__' for Gem::Specification:Class
remote:        ERROR:  Error loading gemspec. Aborting.
remote: -----> Problem building package!
```

My gemspec has this line:
`$:.push File.expand_path('lib', __dir__)`

This gemspec was generated by `rails plugin new`.

This same gemspec is parsed with no issues by `gem build`. My rubygems version is 3.0.3.

Should I not be using `__dir__` in my gemspec?
I can replace the `__dir__` with `__FILE__` but it appears that rubocop prefers `__dir__`.

Answer (score 3):

At this time, Gemfury builder runs Ruby 1.9, which doesn't support `__dir__`.

Like you said, I would recommend doing `File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)` for now.